# R - Get X value for given Y value

Tags: r, normal-distribution, probability-density, density-plot

I have a cumulative distribution function from a standard normal distribution and I have a given y value, which should be `0.95`

```
dist <- function(x) pnorm(x,0,1)
```

How can I solve the equation `0.95 = dist(x)` for x?

Comment: The standard normal distribution function is never equal to `0.95`. I assume you really want the point where the cumulative distribution function equals 0.95. In that case just do `qnorm(.95)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the uniroot function as follows:

```
dist <- function(x) pnorm(x,0,1) - 0.95
uniroot(dist, interval = c(-1,4))
```

which would give you the same answer as qnorm(0.95,0,1).